# Windows 7 not booting,dual boot with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I've dual booted Ubuntu with Ubuntu 12.04. It was working very fine but suddenly yesterday when I tried to boot to windows 7 it displayed "Boot MGR is missing".

I booted into Ubuntu and used Boot-repair but when I rebooted to windows 7 it just restarted the machine without even displaying Boot MGR is missing. I've also tried restoring MGR with boot repair but it didn't work either. I've tried nerosmart easy recovery but it didn't display any drive and also in Ubuntu when I did `os-prober` it displayed windows 7. So what should I do now?

Comment: Do you usually mount and read/write the Windows system partition from Ubuntu? If so, please stop doing that as your Windows may not boot properly. Note that I'm not saying that's what happened but it's one possibility. Anyway, now you need Windows recovery tools. It has nothing to do (and cannot be solved) with Ubuntu or Grub.

Comment: Does Windows still show as a choice in your grub menu when you boot?

Comment: @L.D.James   It does show, before and after Boot Repair. *it was working very fine* then something happened and Windows shows an error message that suggests file system corruption, at least, but that all happens after Grub tries to release control to the Windows bootloader which apparently can't be found due to errors in the Windows partition, not because something changed in the Grub entry for Windows.

Comment: (cont.) To be clear: There wouldn't be any Windows error message if the the Grub entry didn't point to the correct Windows partition/bootloader as it always did, according to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Update your grub with:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot.

It will scan the system and add any found OS to the boot menu.

Comment: It will indeed but that will not solve the issue because the dual booting was working before. The Windows not booting now is *after* Grub and most likely will require Windows recovery tools or may not be recoverable at all.

Comment: I thought he had indicated fixes he had applied but was now missing the Windows option from the Grub menu.

Comment: Just Boot Repair apparently which wasn't expected to work anyway. Boot Repair, at best, fixes Grub entries. It cannot fix Windows itself.

Comment: My reference wasn't in fixing Windows.  It was fixing the dual boot of Ubuntu.  It was my impression that he had, after all his work, successfully boot the system into Ubuntu.  If that is the case, the Ubuntu tools will deal with the MBR.  Other than that, he would need a Windows repair procedure to deal with Windows itself.  Again, his message appeared to indicate he had dealt with the Windows.  So after dealing with Windows (with steps that are provided by our forums such as http://superuser.com).  Bring the missing windows choice back to the Ubuntu menu.

Comment: Exactly, Windows repair procedures to deal with Windows is what's needed from the start and also exactly what I commented above. And off-topic of course, also my point from the start. There wasn't and isn't a problem with the dual boot, it's made clear more than once in the OP and because you misread/misunderstood it you gave an answer that actually isn't one, it's mostly likely unneeded and unrelated to the actual (off-topic) problem.